# Erro de conexão entre Java e postgresql

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um  interface gráfica em Java se conectar com um banco de dados, para tanto estou usando o Netbenas e o Postegresql.
Criei uma tabela no  Postegresql.
Baixei o  postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar e  o adicionei  no projeto.
Tenho duas Classes uma da conexão e a outra do Form, mas quando eu tento conectar sai essa mensagem:

```
Java.sql.SQLExeption: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
```

Alguém sabe o que isso significa ?
OBS : Como é um teste fiz a interface no editor do Netbeans.
Segue as classes:

```
    package Visual;
import java.sql.*;
import Dal.ConectaBd;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class frmlogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    public frmlogin() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        con=ConectaBd.Conectabd();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
 /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new frmlogin().setVisible(true);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(frmlogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Segunda classe :

```
package Dal;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ConectaBd {
    public static Connection Conectabd() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
          // conecta com o banco
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432","postgres","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com sucesso");
            return con;
        }catch(SQLException erro){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, erro);
            return null;
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que adicionou o jar do drive no classpath? Verifique novamente.

Comment: oi Renam geralmente quando baixamos o psql ele tem um menu que solicita a instalação dos drivers isso aconteceu com vc.

Comment: Verifique se o drive esta na sua aplicação
o postgresl está instalado na mesma maquina que a aplicação?
A senha é mesmo em branco?
O firewall esta habilitado?